# How to make an element full screen in polymer 2.0?

Tags: html, css, polymer, custom-element, polymer-2.x

I have an element called `my-app`, and its body and html are set to 100%.

Inside `my-app` I have another element called `background-section` with its body and html are set to 100%. And in this element I have a section with background image. I want this background image to be full screen.

```html
<section class="background-section">
  <!-- this is another element -->
  <nav-bar></nav-bar>
  
  <div class="opening-msg">
    <div class="app-container">
      <h1>Find a perfect <br /> property</h1>
      <span class="caption">
          Connecting landlords & tenants through an easy to <br /> use web
          application built for all devices
        </span>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

```css
.background-section {
  width: 100%;
  background: linear-gradient( rgba(73, 77, 86, 0), rgb(73, 77, 86)), url('../../images/background-img2.jpg') no-repeat;
  background-size: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  height: 100%;
}
```

The issue is, for some reason the image is not going full screen. Not sure why its the case.

Comment: Use `background-size:cover`

Comment: @LokeshGupta Yes I can do that, but what I want is that the image has to be only full screen when you visit the site, and then I scroll down to see other section of the page.

Comment: Then use `Height:100vh;` to get the same. i posted answer as your need

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `height:100vh` and `background-size: cover;` to get hte same.

```css
body, html {margin:0; padding:0;}

.background-section {
  width: 100%;
  background: linear-gradient( rgba(73, 77, 86, 0), rgb(73, 77, 86)), url('https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/originals/90/6e/a5/906ea53ecaa5be963e960daf8b645af2.jpg') no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  height: 100vh;
}
```

```html
<section class="background-section">
  <!-- this is another element -->
  <nav-bar></nav-bar>
  <div class="opening-msg">
    <div class="app-container">
      <h1>Find a perfect <br /> property</h1>
      <span class="caption">
          Connecting landlords & tenants through an easy to <br /> use web
          application built for all devices
        </span>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```